# laravel gate not working in blade with @can

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i create a simple gate with laravel that return true and use it in blade with @can but it not work

here my gate in authserviceprovider

```
Gate::define('isLoginSite', function ($user) {
    return true;
});
```

it just return true.

here my blade

```
@can('isLoginSite')
      <button class='btn btn-success'><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart '></i></button>
@endcan
```

i also cleared cache with

```
php artisan clear:cache
```

Comment: Is the user authenticated?

Comment: use `php artisan cache:clear`